# East and West words

Tags: pattern, word-property

Here are some East words:

> wet, chip, awed, sect, stop, dry, ail, to, gyp, do, stop, an

Here are some West words:

> few, loin, lira, jew, ours, bra, points, line, kid, tea, pots, be

What are the East and West words?

Hint:

> Stackexchange did not allow this question, citing vague "quality standards". Thus, more words have been added. This filler contains entirely words which are neither East nor West, including East, West, hint, and and!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

East words are

> Words that when typed on a keyboard, move right (east)

And west words are

> The opposite, words that when typed move left on a keyboard (west)

Examples for 'awed' and 'points':

> [image]

And all the words in the filler

> Go back and forth so are neither east nor west words. For example, 'EAST' starts at 'E' and then moves west to 'A' before moving east to 'S'.